# What class of Objective-C variable is this?

Tags: objective-c

I am working my way through some Objective-C code that I did not write and have found a variable declaration style that I am unfamiliar with. Can anyone tell me the scope of the variable 'myVar' in the class implementation below? Note that this appears in the '.m' file and not the interface declaration.

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize ivar1, ivar2;

NSString* myVar; // <- What is the intent?

- (id)init {

...

@end
```

To me the intention appears to be similar to that of a member variable. What are the advantages of declaring a variable in this way instead of using an ivar in the @interface declaration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just a plain old global variable.  There's only one instance of it, and it can be accessed by any code within the same file *translation unit* (the final file you get after running the preprocessor).  Other translation units (that is, other `.m` files) can also access that global variable, but in order to do so, they need to use an `extern` statement:

```
extern NSString *myVar;
```

`extern` says "this is the name of a global variable, but it's defined in a different translation unit".  The linker resolves all of the `extern` declarations at link time.

Answer (score 2):

a poorly named global variable...

Comment: To be fair to the original programmer - I did rename the variable to something generic for the purposes of this post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too experienced in ObjC but I'd say that is a global.